# FCM push test message (for single device) not working on IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I have an ionic app on capacitor both for android and ios. Everything works great on my testing environment using Firebase-Cloud-Messaging. I am able to send and receive segment notifications to both devices. The only concern I have is when I try to send a single device notification through FCM interface (send test message) to IOS. The device is not receiving it. I have tried many things already. And since it not working there in interface, it is also not working when i test it though CURL. On the other hand, android is working perfectly. Any suggestions?

Appreciate

Comment: How does you token looks like?

Comment: it is a hexadecimal value for ios

Comment: Then that’s an APNS token, not an FCM token

Comment: that’s what ionic capacitor generates as sample example.  i am obtaining android token the same way, and it works

Comment: Capacitor uses FCM on Android, but APNS on iOS. If you want to use FCM on iOS to send push to specific devices you have to convert the APNS token to FCM token. I think google has an API to do it, or you can also use capacitor-fcm plugin.

Comment: You were right, I installed capacitor-fcm and were able to get the fcm format. I wonder why capacitor doesn't do all in one. Thank you for heads up you saved me.

Comment: because for using FCM you have to add Firebase/Messaging dependency to the project, which is not small. Also, the native way of doing push on iOS is APNS, not FCM, some people might not want FCM while APNS is mandatory (FCM just sends the push to APNS and APNS to the iOS device).

Comment: I'm wondering how all of these videos are able to show everything working fine.  I suppose I should go and ask the authors.  In my case, Android works fine, perfectly, but iOS, I can't even get test cloud messages sent from the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

I did a PR on the capacitor-fcm plugin to change that and if you use FCMPlugin.getToken() you will get on both android and iOs the fcm registration token in question. Also, you can send the test message for a specific topic that you only have this device registered.

Until a new release from capcaitor-fcm is launched, you can install from the PR itself.

https://github.com/stewwan/capacitor-fcm/pull/27